# How to use links returned as response from Paypal Capture API?

Tags: paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

Should I store links for future use e.g. for getting the order details. What if Paypal changed this api to v3. Will V2 API still work?

```
{
  "id": "59852153UW8454325",
  "status": "COMPLETED",
  "payment_source": {
    "paypal": {
      "email_address": "sb-afrwj26664756@personal.example.com",
      "account_id": "B54Y46KJS6GPW",
      "account_status": "VERIFIED",
      "name": {
        "given_name": "John",
        "surname": "Doe"
      },
      "address": {
        "country_code": "GB"
      }
    }
  },
  "purchase_units": [
    {
      "reference_id": "1234856sdf531",
      "shipping": {
        "name": {
          "full_name": "John Doe"
        },
        "address": {
          "address_line_1": "Whittaker House",
          "address_line_2": "2 Whittaker Avenue",
          "admin_area_2": "Richmond",
          "admin_area_1": "Surrey",
          "postal_code": "TW9 1EH",
          "country_code": "GB"
        }
      },
      "payments": {
        "captures": [
          {
            "id": "1FH31606554725940",
            "status": "COMPLETED",
            "amount": {
              "currency_code": "USD",
              "value": "2.00"
            },
            "final_capture": true,
            "seller_protection": {
              "status": "ELIGIBLE",
              "dispute_categories": [
                "ITEM_NOT_RECEIVED",
                "UNAUTHORIZED_TRANSACTION"
              ]
            },
            "seller_receivable_breakdown": {
              "gross_amount": {
                "currency_code": "USD",
                "value": "2.00"
              },
              "paypal_fee": {
                "currency_code": "USD",
                "value": "0.59"
              },
              "net_amount": {
                "currency_code": "USD",
                "value": "1.41"
              }
            },
            "links": [
              {
                "href": "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/payments/captures/1FH31606554725940",
                "rel": "self",
                "method": "GET"
              },
              {
                "href": "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/payments/captures/1FH31606554725940/refund",
                "rel": "refund",
                "method": "POST"
              },
              {
                "href": "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/checkout/orders/59852153UW8454325",
                "rel": "up",
                "method": "GET"
              }
            ],
            "create_time": "2023-07-27T04:41:32Z",
            "update_time": "2023-07-27T04:41:32Z"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ],
  "payer": {
    "name": {
      "given_name": "John",
      "surname": "Doe"
    },
    "email_address": "sb-afrwj26664756@personal.example.com",
    "payer_id": "B54Y46KJS6GPW",
    "address": {
      "country_code": "GB"
    }
  },
  "links": [
    {
      "href": "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/checkout/orders/59852153UW8454325",
      "rel": "self",
      "method": "GET"
    }
  ]
}
```

I saw that few of V1 API urls not found thing, which makes me worry about storing the links with v2.

Please help should I store these links or not.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MmQEH.png)

Answer (score 0):

For accounting purposes, store the PayPal transaction ID value, which is found at `purchase_units[0].payments.captures[0].id`.  Store the total of the transaction, and any other payer details you find useful.  The ID is all you need for accounting and later refund purposes.

For debug purposes, you can store the Order ID and perhaps even the response’s PayPal-Debug-Id HTTP header if you want. This information is only useful if you’re having a conversation with PayPal’s technical support within weeks of an API event taking place. After a month or so there's no purpose to it.

There is no reason to store nor do anything with a URL, your own code should be aware of what to do with the transaction ID (if anything) and what API operations you have implemented (if any) in response to whatever actions (for example, triggering a refund).

Version numbers will not change for a long as an API is live. If an API call with a different version number were ever to exist, its path and parameters would also be arbitrarily different, and any code to use it would be a new integration.